# Jackson serialization: Wrap fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

There is a good known case when we unwrap nested object and write its fields into the main object, and I need to make an inverse task.

I have a POJO:

```
class A {
    private String id = "id1";

    @JsonWrap("properties")
    private String property1 = "...";

    @JsonWrap("properties")
    private String property2 = "...";

    // getters and setters
}
```

Default serializer will produce as expected

```
{
    "id": "id1",
    "property1": "...",    
    "property2": "..."    
}
```

But, my JSON should match some specification, and to do that, I need to wrap `property1` and `property2` inside `properties` wrapper. So the result should looks like:

```
{
    "id": "id1",
    "properties": 
    {
        "property1": "...",
        "property2": "..."
    }
}
```

I don't want to change the structure of the POJO so I see 3 possible ways:

1. Write custom serializer. But as it seems to me, to write such serializer will takes more efforts then serialize objects by hands.
2. Create proxy Java object which will reflect the right structure of JSON, and serialize such proxy.
3. Modify JSON after it have been generated. (I'm afraid it would be a great overhead for rereading and rewriting of JSON).

Does anybody make such Serializer or maybe know another options to generate JSON with the structure I need?

For `custom serializer` I want to reuse standard BeanSerializer, I dont want to write out all fields manually:

1. Hide annotated fields.
2. Write out bean, without annotated fields, but don't close object. (Don't call `jgen.writeEndObject();`)
3. Write out wrapped fields.
4. Close object.

Comment: sgrillon solution is right for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need change your model.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ASerializer.class)
class A {
    private String id;
    private String property1;
    private String property2;

    // getters and setters

    public static class ASerializer extends JsonSerializer<A> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(A value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeStringField("id", value.getId());
            jgen.writeObjectFieldStart("properties");
            jgen.writeStringField("property1", value.getProperty1());
            jgen.writeStringField("property2", value.getProperty2());
            jgen.writeEndObject();
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

**Run in main:**

```
A a = new A();
a.setId("id1");
a.setProperty1("...");
a.setProperty2("...");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();
String json = writer.writeValueAsString(a);
System.out.println(json);
```

**output:**

```
{"id":"id1","properties":{"property1":"...","property2":"..."}}
```

Comment: But it's exactly what I don't want to do. It will cause difficults in other tiers of the application.

Comment: I change the solution. Normally , this solution is exatement what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create a Custom Serializer: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers

Of course, if you are creating Java objects from a similar JSON structure you'll likely need to create a Custom Deserializer as well.

Remember, you can always use reflection to create a 'generic' serializer if you find many of your objects share a similar structure.

Answer (score 0):

To get that functionality without altering your model, take a look at writing a custom serializer to accomplish what Jackson can't figure out natively. We annotate the model class `A` with specific directions to use a defined serializer, and then use the `JsonGenerator` to specifically define the structure we are after.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ASerializer.class)
class A {
    private String field1;
    private String innerField1;
    private String innerField2;
    // getters and setters


    public static class ASerializer extends JsonSerializer<A> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(A value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
                jgen.writeStringField("field1", value.getField1());
                jgen.writeObjectFieldStart("wrapper");
                    jgen.writeStringField("innerField1", value.getInnerField1());
                    jgen.writeStringField("innerField2", value.getInnerField2());
                jgen.writeEndObject();
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

I used a static inner class in this case, but feasibly you can place the Serializer wherever best fits your project structure based on visibility. For one-off special case serializers, this is what I tend to do.

Comment: Sorry, you edited your question while I posted this, this answer uses the original fields, but I assume you can get the idea.

Comment: Yes of course I've got the idea, but I want to use BeanSerializer, I don't wan't to write all fields manually.